# Newbie C programming question

Tags: c

Can anyone explain why the output of this code is 2?  I mistakenly thought it was 3.

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};

int *address = array;

array[0] = 2;
array[1] = array[2];
array[2] = *address;

printf("%d\n", array[2]);

return 0;
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com my friend.

This is not Ubuntu-related.

Comment: Programming questions are not off-topic on this site but this is not the best site to ask programming questions unless they are Ubuntu specific which this isn't.  In future you may wish to ask in [Ubuntu Forums: Programming Talk](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=39) or on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the wrong site to ask such questions. Nevertheless, here is the answer:
`*address` is pointing to `array[0]` which you fill with 2. Then, you put the content of `address`, which is `array[0]=2` into array[2], and print it. As a result, you get 2.

Comment: Ah I see, I get it now, I almost didn't post it but thanks for the answer, I'll post C and coding questions in the Stack overflow community.

Answer (score 3):

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};

int *address = array;      /* address storing arrays first byte address which is array[0] address*/ 

array[0] = 2;              /* array[0]=1 is overwritten to array[0]=2 */
array[1] = array[2];       /* array[1]=2 is overwritten to array[2]=3 */
array[2] = *address;       /* array[2]=3 is overwritten with element in address */

printf("%d\n", array[2]);  /* printing array[2] value which is address which is indeed array[0] value */

return 0;
```

Please post your next qestions related  to c and programming in **Stackover flow** community.https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Awesome, I'll make sure to post C related to Stackover flow.  Thanks!